# Correct way to bind IEnumerable MVVM property that isn't an observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Say I have this domain entity:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's say I need to bind the `Bars` property to a datagrid in a WPF/MVVM app. What is the appropriate way to notify the view that the `Bars` property changed? I see a few options:

1. Change Bars to be an ObservableCollection
2. Create a new property, on the view model, that is an ObservableCollection that is a copy of the real Bars.
3. Refresh the entire view
4. Something else/better?

I could do #1, but I don't like the needs of the view to cause a domain entity to change.

Number 2 seems ok, but a bit hackish.

Number 3 seems inefficient.

What's the best way?

**EDIT**

For completeness, based on Simon's answer, I did this:

```
    public Foo SelectedFoo
    {
        get { return _selectedFoo; }
        set
        {
            _selectedFoo = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(() => this.Foo);

            _bars = new ObservableCollection<Bar>();
            if (_selectedFoo.Bars != null) { _bars.AddRange(_selectedFoo.Bars); }
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(() => this.Bars);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Bar> _bars;

    public ObservableCollection<Bar> Bars
    {
        get { return _bars; }
    }
```

Comment: If you know when it changes, just raise PropertyChanged("Bars") there. If not, n.2 is the correct option.

Comment: I actually tried that before posting this question and it didn't work. Maybe I have something else wrong...

Comment: I'd actually create a separate view model for both `Foo` and `Bar` and use these view models...

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance I just tried `PropertyChanged("Foo")` and that worked. Foo didn't really change, but it caused the Bars property to get recognized as changed. Not sure if this is good practice.

Comment: @BobHorn It's not "good practice" but it works. Imagine if your `Bars` contains a thousand entry and the `Name` property changed. Triggering a change on `Foo` will cause a re-evaluation of `Name` and `Bars` when it's not needed. As soon as your model gets complex, it gets more and more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a best practice kind-of-way, your view should not directly bind to your model: that's what your view model is for. Ideally, you want #2 for maximum separation and a logic to synchronize the change back to the model when it's appropriate.